# MFMailComposer hangs app - no crash report - happens after users upgrade iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

**EDIT: I eventually contacted Apple DTS. After I provided a stackshot from an affected user, DTS decided I should file a bug with Apple BugReporter. So, at this point, I think it's an issue with MFMailComposer, but it's unresolved. The Apple bug number is 13602051**

I have a bug that has been coming up again and again in an app.

Some users who upgrade their iOS version report that they can no longer use the email export in my app, which uses MFMailComposer. The app freezes, and doesn't generate a crash report.

My code is pretty simple, and I can't reproduce the reported bug, but many users have now said this happens after an iOS update. Here is the code:

```
// using ARC, so no reference counting
MFMailComposeViewController* controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
@autoreleasepool {
  if (gpxFilePath) {
    NSData *gpx = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:gpxFilePath];
    [controller addAttachmentData:gpx mimeType:@"text/gpx" fileName:[self cleanFileName]];
    gpx = nil;
  }
}
[controller setSubject:subject];
[controller setMessageBody:body isHTML:YES];
[[MAP_APP_DELEGATE mainController] presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

After this is called, the email view comes up, but then is unresponsive.

Comment: The autorelease pool might be an issue. That pool could have an effect on autoreleased objects created by the mail composer when you add the attachment. I'd get rid of it. Then replace the autoreleased `NSData` with one you alloc/init. But leave the call to `gpx = nil;`. Of course this is hard to test if you can't replicate the problem.

Comment: I actually tried that before, and deployed code to a user to test, but they reported no change. Thanks!

Comment: I had a similar problem with MFMailComposeViewController and UIAppearance elements.  I never found an answer, other than it was a known problem. I'll be watching this question with interest.

Comment: We are not using the UIAppearance API. I also decided to submit a Technical Support request to Apple.

Comment: The autorelease pool may be releasing attachmentData or fileName value on you.  These *should* be retained by controller, but maybe not until presentModalViewController and the associated viewDidLoad, et al.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the next code for iOS 6.1 and it works for me.

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
    mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mailer setSubject:@"subject"];
    User *user = [user_array objectAtIndex:1];
    NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"mail address", nil];
    [mailer setToRecipients:toRecipients];
    NSArray *cc = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"mail address", nil];
    [mailer setCcRecipients:cc];
    NSDictionary *dic = [one array objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *description = [dic objectForKey:@"Description"];

    NSString *emailBody = description;

    [mailer setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
    [self presentViewController:mailer animated:YES completion:nil];
    [mailer release];
}
else
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Failure"
                                                    message:@"Your device doesn't support the composer sheet"
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

Remember that simulator is not able to send e-mail, so alert view will be shown in this case.

Note 1: presentModalViewController is deprecated in iOS 6.0

Note 2: try to send the email without data to check if this is what causes the issue

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem.

```
[[MAP_APP_DELEGATE mainController] presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

 controller = nil;
```